# HashMap<DateTime, ArrayList<Email>>

Tags: java, jodatime

I work on a graph where I visualize my emails. I want to be able to get the emails from a certain day.

Is this a bad way to store?

```
HashMap<DateTime, ArrayList<Email>>
```

Or is it better to convert the date to a string and then use `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Email>>`

Note, the dates are added without hours, minutes and seconds, so just like `06/07/2010` for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime` has properly defined `equals` and `hashcode` methods, so using those as the key in a `HashMap` is perfectly OK. There's not much to be gained by converting them to strings first.

I would suggest, however, that if you only want to store the year/month/day components, then you may want to use `LocalDate` instead of `DateTime`.

Additionally, you could also consider using `TreeMap` rather than `HashMap`, so that your map is automatically sorted by date. Might be handy.